# Button won't redirect to external page

Tags: html, forms

I'm a new developer and learning. The button I am using will submit on enter, but not when pressing the 'submit' button.

Any insight?

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://google.com">
                      <div class="inner-form">
                        <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                          <div class="svg-wrapper">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                              <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                            </svg>
                          </div>
                          <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Paste a domain here" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                          <button class="btn-search" action="https://www.google.com" type="button">SEARCH</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <span class="info">ex. JeepBeef.com</span>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.

Make sure to have the `type` property set to `submit`

```
 <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To submit form you need to change type of button from "button" to "submit"